# Hover dont work properly in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with hover in css. 
I want to create a menu bar using saved png files, each file has it's own div. When I trying to use a class name and hover modifier it works on first element, when pointer moves to the next element, the second and the first elements are hilighted, when it is over third first, second and third are hilighted and etc.... What I have to do to deal with it?
I will be appreciate for any help.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv='Content Type' content="text/html ; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Awantura Sluzewiec</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0     /jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4 /jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: black url('images/background.png') top left no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    header {
      background: url('images/logo_tittle.png') top left no-repeat;
      position: relative;
      top: 25px;
      left: 25px;
      width: 1215px;
      height: 157px;
    }
    nav {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -180px;
      left: 73px;
      width: 1073px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    .navButtons {
      display: block;
      left: 145px;
      position: relative;
      width: 149px;
      height: 40px;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .navButtons:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
    }
    #O_nas {
      background: transparent url('images/o_nas.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Druzyna {
      background: transparent url('images/druzyna.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Treningi {
      background: transparent url('images/treningi.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Obiekt {
      background: transparent url('images/obiekt.png')center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Wyniki {
      background: transparent url('images/wyniki.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Trener {
      background: transparent url('images/trener.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
    #Promil {
      background: transparent url('images/promil.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div></div>
  <nav>
    <div id="O_nas" class="navButtons" </div>
      <div id="Druzyna" class="navButtons" </div>
        <div id="Treningi" class="navButtons" </div>
          <div id="Obiekt" class="navButtons" </div>
            <div id="Wyniki" class="navButtons" </div>
              <div id="Trener" class="navButtons" </div>
                <div id="Promil" class="navButtons" </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are adding hover to the class. So all the items with that class will have the new style applied. Apply the hover to each Id if you want to modify only one item

Comment: your divs aren't closed properly

Comment: `<div id="O_nas" class="navButtons" </div>` is invalid HTML because the starting `<div` is not closed. It should be `<div id="O_nas" class="navButtons">some text/image </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the tabs is your only problem, see here: https://jsbin.com/tehusiqiye/edit?html,output

Please, if you ask Stackoverflow for help on HTML, do use the [W3 HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) **before**, to ensure your HTML is syntactically correct. This service would have have told you what was amiss, saving you time and keeping resources of people here for more important questions.

Comment: Thanks for help it works. I wil keep it on my mind to use HTML validator from now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are saying when i hover over an element with a 'navButtons' class you give it a box shadow or 1px. Now the problem is that every div in you html document has the same class. You can do this, dont need to give each of them an extra class just under each of these just copy and

```
#O_nas {
      background: transparent url('images/o_nas.png') center center no-repeat;
    }
#O_nas:hover {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    }
```